# Can I start jenkins job on my workspace?

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a GIT project integrated to Jenkins. I use shell script for build.

Use-case:
Before commit I want to start a simple and fast test to prevent rubbish in the repository.

Q: Can I start a simple Jenkins test-job (with jenkins's setting and scripts) on my current, local repository/branch with uncommitted files?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Which settings and scripts? You want to start a job, that will run remotely in the Jenkins machine, but you want to perform tests on files you haven't commited and published on the repository yet?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, then yes - assuming that your machine is set up either running Jenkins directly, or as a Jenkins slave.

Then in your test job, set 'Source Code Management' to 'None', and specify the path to your workspace under 'Use custom workspace' (under 'General' - you'll have to click the 'Advanced' button to find it).

That will run whatever script/actions you specify on the files currently in your workspace, without interacting with the git repository.